# Can't get two processes to share data via a kernel object, OpenFileMapping is null

Tags: c, windows, winapi, system

I’ve been reviewing Pavel Yosifovich’s books and videos.  I’ve tried to write a pure C program that creates a kernel object and allows a text string to pass from one process to the other.  My code is below, but for some reason the program that is reading the data the call to OpenFileMapping always returns NULL and get last error is 2, which is file not found.  I have run WinObj and the MySharedMemory object shows up in  \Sessions\2\BaseNamedObjects\MySharedMemory.  I don’t think it is a security issue because the error was file not found, I tried changing the the source to point to Local\MySharedMemory but that makes no difference.  I’ve also tried running in a admin command prompt and it still does not work.  It seems like it has got to be something about the path as it is saying file not found.  Below is the code for the two programs.

*Producer*

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    HANDLE hFileMapping;
    LPVOID lpFileMap;
    char buffer[] = "Windows System Programming is fun!";

    hFileMapping = CreateFileMapping(
        INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,
        NULL,
        PAGE_READWRITE,
        0,
        sizeof(buffer),
        L"MySharedMemory"
        );

    if (hFileMapping == NULL) {
        printf("Error creating file mapping: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    lpFileMap = MapViewOfFile(hFileMapping, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0);

    if (lpFileMap == NULL) {
        printf("Error mapping view of file: %d\n", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
        return 1;
    }

    strcpy((char*)lpFileMap, buffer);
    printf("Data written to shared memory.  Press Enter to exit...\n");
    getchar();
    UnmapViewOfFile(lpFileMap);
    CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
    return 0;
}
```

*Consumer*

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    HANDLE hFileMapping;
    LPVOID lpFileMap;

    hFileMapping = OpenFileMapping(
        FILE_MAP_READ,
        FALSE,
        L"MySharedMemory"
        );

    if (hFileMapping == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file mapping: %d\n", GetLastError());
        getchar();
        return 1;
        
    }

    lpFileMap = MapViewOfFile(
        hFileMapping,
        FILE_MAP_READ,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
        );

    if (lpFileMap == NULL) {
        printf("Error mapping view of file: %d\n", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
        getchar();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Received message: %s\n", (char*)lpFileMap);
    UnmapViewOfFile(lpFileMap);
    getchar();
    CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
    return 0;
}
```

Newest code, but still does not work

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    HANDLE hFileMapping;
    LPVOID lpFileMap;
    char buffer[] = "Windows System Programming is fun!";

    hFileMapping = CreateFileMapping(
        INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,
        NULL,
        PAGE_READWRITE,
        0,
        1 << 12,
        L"MySharedMemory"
        );

    if (hFileMapping == NULL) {
        printf("Error creating file mapping: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    lpFileMap = MapViewOfFile(hFileMapping, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0);

    if (lpFileMap == NULL) {
        printf("Error mapping view of file: %d\n", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
        return 1;
    }

    strcpy((char*)lpFileMap, buffer);
    printf("Data written to shared memory.  Press Enter to exit...\n");
    getchar();
    UnmapViewOfFile(lpFileMap);
    CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
    return 0;
}




#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    HANDLE hFileMapping;
    LPVOID lpFileMap;

    //hFileMapping = OpenFileMapping(
    //  FILE_MAP_READ,
    //  FALSE,
    //  L"MySharedMemory"
    //  );

    hFileMapping = CreateFileMapping(
        INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,
        NULL,
        PAGE_READWRITE,
        0,
        1 << 12,
        L"MySharedMemory"
        );

    if (hFileMapping == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file mapping: %d\n", GetLastError());
        getchar();
        return 1;
        
    }

    lpFileMap = MapViewOfFile(
        hFileMapping,
        FILE_MAP_READ,
        0,
        0,
        1 << 12
        );

    if (lpFileMap == NULL) {
        printf("Error mapping view of file: %d\n", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
        getchar();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Received message: %s\n", (char*)lpFileMap);
    UnmapViewOfFile(lpFileMap);
    getchar();
    CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: are consumer call `OpenFileMapping` before `CloseHandle(hFileMapping);` in producer ?

Comment: No OpenFileMapping comes second, after creation.  It is my understanding that the object must remain in place for OpenFileMapping to open it.  Open two command prompts run producer and hits the getchar() and waits, then run consumer and it should be able to open the object but fails as described.

Comment: you have wrong understanding. after you call `CloseHandle(hFileMapping);` object will be removed from NT namespace and destroyed (if no more links - if you close view(unmap) too). only if you create object with `OBJ_PERMANENT` attribute or call `NtMakePermanentObject` - object still ramain after close. but you not do it. so you and must got error file not found

Comment: @RbMm The call to `getchar()` stops execution until there is input on STDIN.

Comment: Thats right the getchar() blocks the program from exit

Comment: You could try to call `CreateFileMapping()` with a different name in the "Consumer" and check the full name of both objects in WinObj. If one is "\Sessions\2\..." and the other one is "\Sessions\5\...", the problem is that both processes run in different sessions.

Comment: On the development machine it would be \Sessions\2\... because I am running vs2008 on win7 over RemoteApp, but I have tried running in a non remote app which would goto \Session\1\... and it still does not work, but I will try giving two different names and see what WinObj shows.

Comment: @MartinRosenau you are on to something, I changed it so I've got a MyShareMemory1 and MySharedMemory2, but only 1 shows up.  I even put a getchar() right after the CreateFileMapping and it still does not work.  They are the same thing, but only one shows.

Comment: @MartinRosenau,,solved, wow I spent way too long on that, The consumer project was not set to Unicode, so it was marked so just M, I noticed by going in ptocess explorer and viewing each process as it was running and when I looked at consumer it was just the path and then M,  Thank you, you set me on the right path.

Comment: @ChadBotting You could solve this issue by explicitly using the Unicode or non-Unicode function call: Nearly all Windows functions that take strings have a Unicode variant (ending with `W`) and a non-Unicode variant (ending with `A`): `CreateFileMappingW()`, `CreateFileMappingA()`.

Comment: Compiling the code as C++ would have caught the issue at compile time. Running C code through a C++ compiler is a simple way to uncover problems before they are promoted to defects.

Comment: @IInspectable I know C allows some implicit pointer conversions that C++ does not, but would C really allow a `wchar_t*`  to be passed where a `char*` is expected? I would think C would  catch that mistake.

Comment: @RemyLebeau C (the language) [doesn't distinguish](https://godbolt.org/z/Tcoz1Tf1K) between pointer types. Compilers can [issue warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/Ejsfzx85T), but passing a `wchar_t*` to a function expecting a `char*` is perfectly legal. I know it seems crazy to have a type system and then decide not to use it, but C is high-level assembly after all.

Answer (score 0):

As [Martin Rosenau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2705055/martin-rosenau) said, using the Unicode function by explicitly can solve this issue.

The function has a Unicode variant(ending with `W`): `CreateFileMappingW()`.

Comment: I am aware of Unicode and Ansii functions in Windows (and the history of that) and macros that make it so one does not need to worry about that, I simply forgot to set the project settings.  Thanks